# F#: How to print a matrix?

Tags: .net, f#, math.net

I'm using Math.Net and trying to create a matrix with a random Gaussian distribution. Then I trying to print the matrix but can't:

> Successive arguments should be separated by spaces or tupled, and
>   arguments involving function or method applications should be
>   parenthesized

What I'm doing wrong? Taking a look at [examples](https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html#Printing-and-Strings) is misleading me much more.

```
  printfn "%s" (DenseMatrix.random<float> 1000 50 (Normal(1.0, 100.0))).ToString()
```

Comment: You could write `printfn "%O" (DenseMatrix.random<float> 1000 50 (Normal(1.0, 100.0)))`. The `%O` pattern calls `.ToString()` for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the error message says "arguments involving function or method applications should be parenthesized", what that means is that this:

```
printfn "%s" foo.ToString()
```

needs to be written as:

```
printfn "%s" (foo.ToString())
```

So put an extra set of parentheses around your DenseMatrix value and it should work:

```
printfn "%s" ((DenseMatrix.random<float> 1000 50 (Normal(1.0, 100.0))).ToString())
```

The reason for this language design choice gets into advanced topics like [currying](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/currying/) which you probably don't care about right now, so I'll spare you the long explanation.